# execution of Singleton pattern class in php

Tags: php, singleton

For my project i have created a class file named DBAccess.php which is a class designed maintaining singleton pattern i.e this class will have only one instance in the run-time of the project.Now my question is suppose i'm running the project in my computer and my friend is running the project in another computer will both of i share the same instance of DBAccess class or there will be one instance for every activity of mine and another instance for my friend?Actually i have not any broader idea about run-time execution of singleton pattern class.Can any body share ideas

Comment: Please see [this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI&feature=channel). What you are wrong.

Comment: Imagine i'm running windows and my cat is running windows too ,the only thing we'll be sharing is some crappy os. Either rewrite your question and be precise about what your stack is or delete it. Because it sounds stupid. is there a server in your project ? are we supposed to guess what your stack is ? are you creating a socket server or whatever ?